# how to set password of attached devices on SoftLayer ticket

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we are reviewing this api for Ticket function Implementation.
(https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/)

- Create Ticket : createStandardTicket
- Attach device : addAttachedHardware , addAttachedVirtualGuest

I have a question:

The createStandardTicket function can set a password about only one device.

If I have one more devices, how can I set a password about another devices ?

- add the code

  ```
      Ticket.Service service = Ticket.service(client);            
      ticket = service.createStandardTicket(ticket, contents, null, rootPassword, null, null, null, attachmentType);

      service = ticket.asService(client); 

      ...
      if(attachedDevices != null && attachedDevices.size() > 0){
          for(HashMap<String, Object> deviceInfo : attachedDevices){
              if(DeviceType.from(deviceInfo.get("deviceType").toString()) == DeviceType.BAREMETAL_SERVER){
                  service.addAttachedHardware(Long.parseLong(deviceInfo.get("deviceId").toString()));
              }else if(DeviceType.from(deviceInfo.get("deviceType").toString()) == DeviceType.VIRTUAL_SERVER){
                  service.addAttachedVirtualGuest(Long.parseLong(deviceInfo.get("deviceId").toString()));
              }   
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: If I were you, I would directly try it for some tests.

Comment: @Hearen i already tried that and my application can submit a ticket with one more attached device. but at softlayer to check a attached server, they know a password of each server.but createStandardTicket provides only one password parameter, I can't find a way that sets a password about each attached device.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the password for the first device by using the createStandardTicket or createAdministrativeTicket methods, and there isn't a way to set the password for next attached devices because the addAttachedHardware and addAttachedVirtualGuest  only requires the ID of the device.

I'm sure you are trying to set the passwords like in the portal page but this is not possible through the API, this was reported to Softlayer but there isn't an ETA.